# Can't open Bot Framework Composer from Azure Portal on Linux Mint 20.2

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer, linux-mint-19

I have installed the Bot Framework Composer on Linux Mint 20.2. I have created an Azure Bot in the Azure portal and want to open it with the Composer. When I click on the link `Open in Composer` in the portal, nothing happens. If I copy the link provided into a browser tab, the browser doesn't know what to do with it. What do I need to do to make this work?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think linux mint is not officially supported by BF composer. Are you able to launch composer directly after the install?

Comment: Yes, I can open composer